# SQLite + Virtual File System?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jimfs

I'm using an [`SQLite`](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) database and I want to open a `.db` file from within a [`Jimfs`](https://github.com/google/jimfs) virtual file system. Using the following code I can import a file into the virtual file system:

```
String databaseFilePath = "...";
Configuration configuration = Configuration.unix();
FileSystem fileSystem = Jimfs.newFileSystem(configuration);
Path targetDirectory = fileSystem.getPath("/");
Files.copy(Paths.get(databaseFilePath), targetDirectory);
```

Next, when I try to open the database file, I'm running into problems:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + databaseFileName);
```

I cannot use `String`s since the virtual file can only be referenced using the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object. How do I open a database connection using `Path`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite works on 'real' files.

To be able to store data elsewhere, you have to implement your own SQLite [VFS](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html). (This is not supported by every JDBC driver.)